# Endless loop while using Files.walkFileTree with FOLLOW_LINK on

Tags: java, file, nio

By using the method `Files.walkFileTree(Path, Set<FileVisitOption>, int, FileVisitor)` with FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS on.
I get an endless loop with symbolic links redirecting to parent directory.. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) java tutorial explains a way how to detect the particular symbolic link causing the issue with the following instructions:

> The visitFile method is invoked for files. If you have specified the `FOLLOW_LINKS` option and your file tree has a circular link to a
>   parent directory, the looping directory is reported in the
>   `visitFileFailed` method with the `FileSystemLoopException`. The following
>   code snippet shows how to catch a circular link and is from the Copy
>   example:

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult
    visitFileFailed(Path file,
        IOException exc) {
    if (exc instanceof FileSystemLoopException) {
        System.err.println("cycle detected: " + file);
    } else {
        System.err.format("Unable to copy:" + " %s: %s%n", file, exc);
    }
    return CONTINUE;
}
```

It works, it detects the particular file.. However the endless loop remains. How could I proceed to skip only the Symbolic links creating the issue in order to explore the whole FileTree without ending up in an endless loop?

Comment: I could save the filename causing the exception in a static list and then checking in fileVisit if the current file is present in the static list containing all the "circular" symbolic links..

Comment: Any other input would be more than welcome.

Comment: Does method `visitFileFailed` get invoked in your case?

Comment: @NishantShreshth Yes it does get invoked.

Comment: However saving the the file name in a static list(in visitFileFailed) and then checking in fileVisit if the current file is contained in that static list works only with System.exit(-1) but if instead I would use return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE; it would continue endlessly

Comment: It would be useful having something to say: Ok for this fil do not follow symbolic links.. but there is nothing.. or at least nothing comes up to my mind at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you return `FileVisitResult.CONTINUE`. The [javadoc](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileVisitResult.html) says there are three other values in this enum: `SKIP_SIBLINGS`, `SKIP_SUBTREE` and `TERMINATE`. You could try to use one of them whatever is best for your situation.

Comment: In visitFileFailed the only usable enum is CONTINUE; even if you use SKIP_SUBTREE is going to be treated like continue; SKIP_SUBTREE makes sense only in preVisitDirectory

Answer (score 0):

When walking the file tree with FOLLOW_LINKS and a symbolic link is encountered which would cause a loop back to an ancestor directory:

- neither preVisitDirectory or postVisitDirectory will be called for the link
- only visitFileFailed will be called for the link
- the link will not be followed

As you can see, the file tree walker logic already prevents infinite recursion of this type, and therefore nothing is necessarily wrong with simply logging an error message.

However, something else must be causing the infinite loop in your program. Perhaps you have created a circular reference in your filesystem using hard links?